# Replace import of constant by static import in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search, static-import

I have a code with some constants in format ClassName.CONSTANT_NAME. I want to quickly replace this by CONSTANT_NAME. But I have not found any efficient way of doing that.
Every time I want to static import something I have to:

```
alt + enter
Add on demand static import for ....
```

for each class. But there is ~1000 classes

Is there any quick way of converting import to static import for many classes?

Comment: I assume this would be dependent on your IDE. I do not believe IntelliJ has such a feature built in. You might be able to accomplish this by writing a separate application that modifies your Java source code one time, though.

Comment: find and replace seems to be the only solution I guess, both the `import` line and the actual Constant name.

Comment: I don't know which ide you use, but maybe you can use refactoring methods, for example the method rename. With this you can change the same code simultaneously on all positions

Comment: I think you might get something here https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/01/intellij-idea-16-eap-makes-it-easier-to-add-static-imports/  *add unambiguous imports on the fly*

Comment: nullpointer, "add unambiguous imports on the fly" unforunetly it doesn't work for me(i should open every file in ide to perform autoimports - it's not fully automatically). I don't know why.
But first comment seems like it is a solution for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Structural Search & Replace is a good way to do this.

Search template: `ClassName.CONSTANT_NAME`
Replace template: `ClassName.CONSTANT_NAME`

And make sure you have selected the checkbox `Use static import`. This will add the static import for you.

[image: Structural Replace dialog from IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3]